# ProFormFieldSet affecting ProFormText addonBefore attribute text to disappear?

Tags: antd, ant-design-pro

I am trying to add some text before each Proformtext component, but it is not appearing

Below is my code

```
  <ProFormFieldSet
     name="firstrow"
     label={<span style={{fontSize: fontSize}}>A</span>}
     labelAlign={labelAlignment}
    >
      <ProFormText
        addonBefore="helloworld"
        labelAlign={labelAlignment}
        width="md"
      />
              =
     <ProFormText
        addonBefore={C}
        width="md" />
  </ProFormFieldSet>
```

**This is the Actual result**
[image]

**Expected Result**

There is text beside each input.

**What I have tried**

I took ProFormText component out from ProFormFieldSet and the text appear. anyone know why this is happening??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the reference, the props we set for ProFormText are actually for Form.Item, and the fieldProps are for the included Input, remember. [pro-form-fields-reference](https://procomponents.ant.design/en-US/components/field-set)
have a try like below

```
<ProFormFieldSet
     name="firstrow"
     label={<span style={{fontSize: fontSize}}>A</span>}
     labelAlign={labelAlignment}
    >
      <ProFormText
        fieldProps={{addonBefore:"helloworld"}}
        labelAlign={labelAlignment}
        width="md"
      />
              =
     <ProFormText
        fieldProps={{addonBefore: C}}
        width="md" />
  </ProFormFieldSet>
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helps